# communication between fragments of fragment tab host

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, fragment, fragment-tab-host

I am implementing tabs using FragmentTabHost of v4 support library.

My first tab contains the list of items.When I click on list item it should move to tab 2.
My second tab shows the description of the list item.So I need to pass the list of the first tab and the index of list item clicked to the second tab.

I am currently using getters and setters at application level. But is there any other way to do so? What is the best way to do this?

First fragment-Tab-0

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mCallback = (OnRadioSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);          
        mCallback.onRadioSelected(dataList, position);
}



public interface OnRadioSelectedListener {
    public void onRadioSelected(ArrayList<DataModel> playingList, int   playingIndex);
}
```

Tabhost activity code:

```
@Override
    public void onRadioSelected(ArrayList<DataModel> playingList, int playingIndex) {
        mPlayingIndex = playingIndex;
        mPlayingList = playingList;

       fragmentTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
        Fragment2 frag = (Fragment2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getString(R.string.str));
    if (frag != null) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("Key_list", mPlayingList);
        args.putInt("Key_current_index", mPlayingIndex);
        frag.setArguments(args);
    }


}
```

first time frag is null and second time it gives the exception

Comment: post some of the code, so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out this developer article on Communicating with other fragments:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

In short, you have your `Activity` implement an interface which all fragments use to communicate with each other. When a fragment needs to do something, it asks the `Activity` to handle the behavior.

So if `fragment1` wants to go to `fragment2`, `fragment1` calls `YourActivity.goToFragment2()` (or whatever), and `YourActivity` will handle it. eg:

```
public void goToFragment2(){
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab (indexOfFragment2Here);
}
```

You need to ensure your `Activity` implements the interface, so check out the implementation of `Fragment.onAttach(Activity activity)` in the "Define a Interface" section: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface

Comment: Ani, first of all thanks for reply.I checked this link.I am getting the callback in my activity.But thing i am not able to do is how to transfer data from activity to the second fragment.I am using setCurrentTab(1) method to change the tab.

Comment: @vs.thaakur If you have a reference to the fragments in your activity, you can pass the data as arguments in the  `goToFragment2(Object someData)`method. Within `goToFragment2(...)` you pass those arguments to your fragment using a setters within your second fragment (eg. fragment2.setData(someData)). Hope that helps :)

Comment: The main problem is of the reference of the fragments in activity.I tried it by overriding onAttachFragment method of the activiy but it is called only once for each tab.

Comment: @vs.thaakur The onAttach behaviour is correct, its triggered when the fragment is 'linked' to the activity. Having the references should be handled within the activity, when you're setting up the FragmentTabHost. I had a looksee on google, try these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898233/getting-reference-to-nested-fragment-from-fragmenttabhost and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804560/fragmenttabhost-fragments-how-do-i-pass-data-between-tabs ?  They retrieve the fragment using the `FragmentManager` and either a tag or an id

Comment: its not working.I used findfragmentbytag but it throws illegalStateException:fragment already active when I use setArgument method on this fragment

Comment: @vs.thaakur sorry it took a little to get back to you. I haven't been able to figure out a good approach for you. I gave it a shot in a sample project, but the `FragmentTabHost` only loads `Fragments` when they're first viewed, which could cause issues if you don't use a handler to delay operations (eg. when you change tabs and onAttach gets called you triggers a setter. If the fragment object in your activity is null, you use a handler to delay the operation so the fragment actually has a chance to call the setter in onAttach).

Comment: @vs.thaakur You could try an alternative like a `ViewPager` with a `PagerTitleStrip` (https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html). If you want to disable swiping in the `ViewPager`, use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s . Since a `ViewPager` uses a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` or `FragmentPagerAdapter`, you can initialize your Fragments beforehand and hold a reference to them in a custom implementation of the Fragment(State)PagerAdapter

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a little old but if anyone is still interested in knowing an easy way to do this ,here i go. So the problem is sending data between two fragments right , so basically what you have to start with is create a function which returns a string in your Activity. Something like

```
String TabFragmentB;
public void setTabFragmentB(String t){
    TabFragmentB = t;
}
public String getTabFragmentB(){
    return TabFragmentB;
}
```

This is just getter and setter for a String TabFragmantB.
This will return you the tag of the Fragment to which you are sending data(Lets call it Fragment B).So the code in Fragment B will look something like this ,write it in the onCreateView section itself.

```
String myTag = getTag();

    ((YourActivity)getActivity()).setTabFragmentB(myTag);
```

This code will return you the tag of Fragmant B to our activity.

Also in Fragmant B create a function which takes in the type of data you want to take in FragmantB.
In this case

```
 public void Fucntion_FragmantB(List<YourObject> ob)
{
    //DO ANYTHING WITH THE DATA
}
```

Now Half the work is done ,lets move to Fragmant A,
Here it goes something like this.

```
 List<YourObject> ob=new List<YourObject>();
 String TabOfFragmentB = ((Your_ACTIVITY)getActivity()).getTabFragmentB();

                    Statistics_Fragment fragmentB = (FragmentB)getActivity()
                            .getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentByTag(TabOfFragmentB);

                    fragmentB.Fucntion_FragmantB(ob);
```

Note that by changing the functions in Fragment A and B ,you can pass any type of data.

Hope this works for everyone ,because it did for me.

Feel free to make changes.