# Pass values to tab fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I have two tabs in a `FragmentTabHost` - and my question is how can I pass data to the selected fragment?

Here is my code:

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("clips").setIndicator(("Clips")),
                MyClipsFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("clipboards").setIndicator("Clipboards"),
                FragmentSearchMyClipboards.class, null);
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467612/communication-between-fragments-of-fragment-tab-host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the bundle (3ed parameter)

```
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle()
myBundle.putInt("paramKey", 1);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("clips").setIndicator(("Clips")),
                MyClipsFragment.class, myBundle);
```

Comment: It complains about the last parameter being a bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem comes down to communicate between two fragments. The only way is through the activity which holds both the `fragment`. This can be done via declaring one interface in both the  fragments and implementing them in the activity. Try to read here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to communicate through fragments is using EventBus - https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

HowTo:
1. Add these line to fragment that needs to get the information:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list, container, false);

    }

@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
public void onEventMainThread(EventBusMsg bus) { //Name your method like this   
        //here you get the info...
    }
```

2. Post the information from anywhere, like this:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventBusMsg(true));
```

3. Make class of the object you are going to post:

   ```
   public class EventBusMsg {
   ```

   //some info...
   }