# Get fragment in Tabhost is null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have made a tab container with TabHost,  the layout xml file is like below:

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dip" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:name="com.test.Tab1Fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/tab5"
            android:name="com.test.Tab5Fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

In MainActivity, I init and add tab into activity in `onCreate` callback like this,

```
tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup(); 
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(mRes.getString(R.string.tab1)).setContent(R.id.tab1));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab5").setIndicator(mRes.getString(R.string.tab5)).setContent(R.id.tab5));
```

On the tab changed, I want to find the current fragment, and do some init while current fragment is showing.

```
private OnTabChangeListener tabChangedListener = new OnTabChangeListener() {
        public void onTabChanged(String tabid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "tab changed " + tabid);
            currentTab = tabid;
            TabChangeCallback currentFragment = (TabChangeCallback) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentTab);
            if(currentFragment != null) {
                currentFragment.onTabChanged(currentTabIndex);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get fragment null ");
            }   
        }
    };
```

Question is why `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentTab)` is return null, and I couldn't call the fragment init code. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you are dealing with only fragment in the Tabhost then you better use [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html). It will be more optimized and easy.

[Example](http://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/)

And getting child fragment by Tag - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898233/getting-reference-to-nested-fragment-from-fragmenttabhost?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: thanks, with your help I solved this problem. This works for me

Comment: Having same question. Do it in onTabChanged() the Fragment frgmt = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tabTag); return null. Could you post what is your working solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because the fragemnt has not created at the time OnTabChnaged gets called.
[Please check my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293549/how-to-get-the-content-fragment-at-ontabchangedstring-tabtag/31920206#31920206)